# Can we use select2 inside the dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, jquery-select2

I am working in asp.net core. I am using typescript. I am using select2.

HTML:-

```
<select multiple id="e1" class="js-example-basic-multiple js-states form-control">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
    <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
    <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Script:-

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
    });
</script>
```

css and js:-

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

This is my code for select2. I am using select2 inside the modal dialog. When using select2 inside the dialog, it does not work.

I check like using select2 outside of the modal dialog, it works fine.

Can we able to use select2 inside of the modal dialog? If yes means, how?

Version of select2: 4.0.3

Comment: You need to initialise the `select2()` library *after* the modal has been shown. To do that you can hook to the events in whatever modal library you use.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine inside modal too. (check snippet)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();

  $("#dialog").dialog();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <select multiple id="e1" class="js-example-basic-multiple js-states form-control">
 
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
  <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
  <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </select>
</div>
```